# How to get number of apks that can handle a particular activity?

Tags: android, adb

I want to find out how many apks can handle a particular activity and depending on that do some action. For example if I do

```
adb shell am start -a android.media.action.STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA
```

It is going to open the camera BUT if there are multiple apks which are doing the same activity then I will get the popular "Finish action using" dialog. I am trying to avoid that.

So, If there is any way for me to know number of apks that support that activity then I can say

```
if(numberofApk>1)
{
 Keypress.click  //to remove finish action using dialog
}
else
//do nothing
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

As per documentation here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#Verify if you have your intent defined you just go with:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
activities.size() //number of stuff that can handle your intent
```

Comment: I need adb command though. I am not working on an apk. I Commandline automation framework built upon adb